# Intersecting figures reckoning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to find out a way to calculate the amount of times one or multiple figures like squares/rectangles of different colors are intercepted by other squares/rectangles in a PNG picture. The goal is to write a function that loads a PNG picture as a matrix containing tuples wherein each tuple represents a color pixel in the RGB color mode:

E.g. black = (0,0,0), white = (255,255,255), red = (255,0,0), etc.

Determine how many times a figure is overlapped by other figures and save the information in a dictionary where each key represents the figure color and each value represents the interceptions of the same figure.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, all squares have different colors. I tried to solve this with the following function.

```
import images
def intersections_reckoning(image_filename):
    
    white = (255,255,255)
    overlapping = {}
    img = images.load(image_filename)
    for i in img:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            count = 0
            if i[j] == white:  
                continue
            elif i[j] != i[j-1]:
                count +=1
                overlapping[i[j-1]] = count
    return overlapping
```

Which gives me the following wrong output:

```
{(255, 255, 255): 1,
 (255, 0, 0): 1,
 (0, 0, 255): 1,
 (0, 255, 0): 1,
 (255, 255, 0): 1}
```

Instead of

```
{(255, 0, 0): 4, --> red square is overlapped 4 times 
 (0, 0, 255): 0, --> blue square is not overlapped by any other figures. It intercepts others though 
 (0, 255, 0): 2, --> green square is overlapped twice
 (255, 255, 0): 2} --> yellow square is overlapped twice
```

How should i solve this?. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about your method. My approach would be to move around the image with two for loops, follow the border of each encountered rectangle, then you exit the loop and you have in store a list which contains the coordinates of the corners of all rectangles. Once this is done, use math to determine the intersections to other squares. You could also bruteforce it if you don't care about efficiency and check whether `set(XY1) intersects set(XY2)` for XY1 XY2 the lists of coordinates of a pair of rectangles.

Comment: would you use nested loops?

Comment: Well, two nested loops to check every pixel (`img[i][j]`), then a loop to iterate over the shapes.

Comment: @Guimoute Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

First, we parse the image and looks for colored segments. We add their x or y coordinate to a dictionary depending on whether those segments are vertical or horizontal. That gives us, for each colored rectangle, a dict of four coordinates `x1, y1, x2, y2` which represent the **corners** of that rectangle. From there I think you can easily do some math and calculate if rectangles intersect with each other.

The reason I use segments instead of neighbour checks is because otherwise this method would fail if the intersection with another rectangle *is* the corner.

Caveat: my method fails in the edge case where the intersection with another rectangle is an entire side of the rectangle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create the image and rectangles.
N = 10
image = np.ones((N, N, 3), dtype=np.uint8)*255

blue = (0, 0, 255)
image[1, 2:6] = blue
image[1:6, 6] = blue
image[5, 2:6] = blue
image[2:6, 2] = blue

red = (255, 0, 0)
image[4, 5:9] = red
image[4:9, 5] = red
image[8, 5:9] = red
image[4:9, 9] = red

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, N)
ax.set_ylim(0, N)
ax.imshow(image)
```

[image]

```
# Search for corners.
(X, Y, _) = image.shape
shapes = {}
for (name, color) in (("blue", blue), ("red", red)):
    shape = shapes[name] = {}

    # Searching for horizontal segments.
    for x in range(X):
        right_color = [True for b in image[x, :, :] == color if b.all()]
        if len(right_color) >= 3:
            if shape.get("x1") is None:
                shape["x1"] = x
            elif shape.get("x2") is None:
                shape["x2"] = x

    # Searching for vertical segments.
    for y in range(Y):
        right_color = [True for b in image[:, y, :] == color if b.all()]
        if len(right_color) >= 3:
            if shape.get("y1") is None:
                shape["y1"] = y
            elif shape.get("y2") is None:
                shape["y2"] = y

print(shapes["blue"])
# >>> {'x1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'y1': 2, 'y2': 6}
print(shapes["red"])
# >>> {'x1': 4, 'x2': 8, 'y1': 5, 'y2': 9}

# Find the intersections.
NotImplemented
```